# When can we write the square of a matrix as the product of the matrix and its transpose?

Tags: matrices, products

I often see something like $(A - B)^2$ being written as $(A - B)(A - B)^T$ . Here $A$ and $B$ are two matrices. I can see that this is possible when $A$ and $B$ are scalars (i.e) single element matrices. In what other cases does this equality hold ?

Comment: Say $A-B$ is symmetric. And maybe your observation contains misunderstanding. $(A-B)^2$ and $(A-B)(A-B)^T$ has totally different meanings. It's not about writing style.

Comment: Makes Sense. Thanks Shuchang. Yes, I understand that it has nothing to do with writing style. I just wanted to know when we could jump between the two. I see this being done a lot in textbooks having derivations.

Comment: It's very rarely correct to say $(A-B)^2=(A-B)(A-B)^T$. Essentially, it is only true if $A-B$ is symmetric. Saying you "often" see something makes it very hard to figure out whether the argument is wrong, or the context allows this due to symmetry - please be specific with examples.

Comment: There is a case *like* this, where $A,B$ are row vectors, then $$\left|A-B\right|^2 = (A-B)(A-B)^T$$

Comment: @Bob It might not be. But you are referring to derivatives. It's highly possible the textbooks read $||A-B||^2$, in which case they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there are two related questions operative here; the first is the question as posed in the title, which I take to apply to any square matrix $C$:  when can we write $C^2 = CC^T$? that is, what special properties must $C$ possess which would imply, or be implied by,  $C^2 = CC^T$?  The second question, which is really only a minor variation of the first, asks what happens when $C$ is represented in the special form $C = A - B$, so that we have $(A - B)(A - B) = (A - B)(A^T - B^T)$.  But the equivalence of these two views is easily seen:  since $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, any $C$ may be written in the form $A - B$ by simply taking $A = C$, $B = 0$; furthermore, by fixing $C$ and taking $A = B + C$, and letting $B$ range over the set of all $B$ square matrices, we see that all pairs of matrices $A$, $B$ with $C = A - B$ may be so obtained.  And since nothing further has been specified concerning $A$ and $B$, e.g. there is no special relationship between them which might give $C = A - B$ some additional structure, we might as well enjoy the at least the notational convenience of working with $C$.  Results can always be translated back to the $A - B$ form if so desired.

So when *does* $C^2 = CC^T$ hold?  Well, as we used to say out west at old Caltech, it is "trivially obvious to even the most casual observer" that $C$ symmetric, that is, $C =C^T$, implies $C^2 = CC^T$.  But wait!  There's more!  Suppose we write the equation $C^2 = CC^T$ in the form

$C(C - C^T) = 0; \tag{1}$

from (1) we see that in the event that $C$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists C^{-1}$, then upon left multiplication by $C^{-1}$ we obtain

$C - C^T = 0 \Rightarrow C = C^T \tag{2}$

i.e. $C$ must be symmetric in this case.  If, the other hand, we assume $C - C^T$ is invertible, we immediately run into trouble:  if $\exists (C - C^T)^{-1}$, then right multiplication of (1) by $(C - C^T)^{-1}$ yields

$C = 0; \tag{3}$

but (3) forces

$C - C^T = 0 - 0 = 0, \tag{4}$

and this contradiction shows that $C - C^T$ *cannot* have an inverse if

$C^2 = CC^T. \tag{5}$

Closer scrutiny of the matrix $C - C^T$, the right-hand factor in (1), reveals that it is in fact *skew-symmetric*, that is

$(C - C^T)^T = C^T - (C^T)^T = C^T - C = -(C - C^T); \tag{6}$

indeed, $C$, as may any other matrix, be decomposed into *unique* symmetric and skew-symmetric parts, $C_+ = C_+^T$ and $C_-= -C_-^T$:

$C = C_+ + C_-, \tag{7}$

and if we take the transpose of (7) we see that

$C^T = C_+^T + C_-^T = C_+ - C_-; \tag{8}$

(7) and (8) may be solved for $C_+$ and $C_-$ by adding and subtracting them, yielding

$C_+ = \dfrac{1}{2}(C + C^T); \; C_- = \dfrac{1}{2}(C - C^T), \tag{9}$

and if the equations (9) are inserted into (1) we see that

$2(C_+ + C_-)C_- = 0 \Leftrightarrow (C_+ + C_-)C_- = 0; \tag{10}$

from (10) we have

$(C_+ + C_-)C_- = C_+C_- + C_-^2 = 0, \tag{11}$

or

$C_+C_- = -C_-^2. \tag{12}$

We next observe that, though $C_-$ is skew-symmetric, $C_-^2$ is in fact symmetric:

$(C_-^2)^T = (C_-C_-)^T = C_-^TC_-^T = (-C_-)(-C_-) = C_-^2, \tag{13}$

and so $-C_-^2$ is also symmetric; by transposing (12) we see that

$-C_-C_+ = C_-^TC_+^T = (C_+C_-)^T = (-C_-^2)^T = -C_-^2 = C_+C_-. \tag{14}$

(12)-(14) show that, for (5) to hold, the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts of $C$ must satisfy

$C_+C_- =  -C_-^2 = -C_-C_+. \tag{15}$

Having sifted through various implications of (5) we have finally found one, (12), which is both necessary *and* sufficient.  The necessity of (12), given (5), has just been shown.  That (5) follows from (12) is also easy to see; just take a walk backwards from (12) to (5); the essential steps are all logically bidirectional.

(15) in fact shows that $C_+$ and $C_-$ must in fact *anticommute*, i.e.

$C_+C_- + C_-C_+ = 0; \tag{16}$

we also see that $C_+C_- + C_-C_+$ is skew-symmetric, whether it happens to vanish or not:

$(C_+C_- + C_-C_+)^T = -C_-C_+ - C_+C_- = -(C_+C_- + C_-C_+); \tag{17}$

it is in fact in general the skew-symmetric part of $C^2$, as may be seen from

$C^2 = (C_+ + C_-)^2 = (C_+^2 + C_-^2) + (C_+C_- + C_-C_+); \tag{18}$

Note that $C_+^2 + C_-^2$ is symmetric, as we have seen; just as we have seen that $C_+C_- + C_-C_+$ is skew; the decomposition into symmetric and skew-symmetric parts being unique, the formula (18) expresses the only such decomposition of $C^2$; in the specific case at hand, $C^2 = CC^T$, we see that this reduces to

$C^2 = (C_+ + C_-)^2 = C_+^2 + C_-^2 \tag{19}$

by virtue of (16).

Well, this shows the kinds of structural properties $C$ must have for $C^2 = CC^T$ to apply.  I think that by digging further along these veins more could be unearthed, but that's as far as I'm taking it for the moment.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

In the answer of Robert, his condition (12) $C_+C_-=-{C_-}^2$ is exactly the same as the hypothesis $C^2=CC^T$. More seriously, we prove the following:

Proposition: Let $C\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $CC^T=C^2$. Then $C$ is symmetric.

Proof: $C^2$ is a symmetric real matrix s.t. $C^2\geq 0$. We may assume $C^2=diag(0_k,U)$ where $U>0$. $C$ and $C^2$ commute ; then $C=diag(V,W)$ where $V,W$ are real matrix s.t. $VV^T=V^2=0_k$ and $WW^T=W^2=U$. Clearly $W$ is invertible and consequently symmetric. Now $VV^T=0_k$ implies that the singular values of $V$ are zero. Thus $V=0_k$ and we are done.

Remark: The problem is more difficult over $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ except if we replace $C^T$ with $C^*$.